# Jquery val get value from attribute html not what user has input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click','.addToCart',function(){
    a = $(this).data('code');
    b = $('#qty-'+a, this).val();
    // b = $('#input[name=qty-'+a+']').val();
    // b = $('#qty-quick-view', this).val();
    c = $('input[name=first_attribute]:checked').val();
    price = $(this).data('price');
    images = $(this).data('images');
    if($(this).hasClass('empty')){
        return false;
    }
    console.log(b);
    return false

    if($('.second-attribute').length > 0){
        d = $('input[name=second_attribute]:checked').val();
    }else{
        d = '';
    }

    e = {code:a,qty:b,first:c,second:d,'price':price,'images':images};

    if(b != ''){
        $.postdata($.root()+'order/add',e).done(function(data){

            if(data.status == 'out of stock'){
                alert('This product is out of stock');
            }else if (data.status == 'stock is not sufficient'){
                // alert('Sorry for inconvenient, ready stock '+data.qty);
                $('#qty-'+a).focus();
                $('#appendAlertStock').append($.texterror("Sorry only "+data.qty+" ready stock"));
                $('#qty-'+a).val(data.qty);
            }else{
                $('.total-cart').html(data.total);
                $('.mini-cart-autoload').load($.root()+'order/minicart');
                if($(window).width() > 1000){
                    $('.notif-cart,.head-header-right > li > ul').slideDown();
                }else{
                    $('.notif-cart,.small_cart').slideDown();
                }
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".notif-cart").slideUp(500, function(){
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                }, 2000);
                $('#quick-view-modal').modal('hide');
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            }
        });
    }else{
        alert ('Fill quantity column');
    }
    return false;
});
```

that is my jquery code to get the value from specified input that I have defined by id.

In this case, for example I have 2 pages that using the same id, in the first page the val return number that user has been input but when I get to the second one, I get only the number from HTML value attribute

Here is the HTML from different page (but they are same)

first page:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h5>{{trans('general.choose-quantity')}}: </h5>
  <input type="number" class="form-control availability-product" 
         value="1" id="qty-{{$product['id']}}" 
         name="qty-{{$product['id']}}" max="{{$firstchild[0]->stock}}">
</div>
<!-- col-md-6 -->
```

second page:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h5>{{trans('general.choose-quantity')}}: </h5>
  <input type="number" class="form-control availability-product" 
         value="1" id="qty-{{$product['id']}}" 
         name="qty-{{$product['id']}}" max="{{$firstchild[0]->stock}}">
</div>
<!-- col-md-6 -->
```

What I have done but failed

1. Changing the id into separate id, the result is that both of input return undefined
2. checking the id repetition in the same page but I think that's not the case

This bug is taking a my whole day to figure, did anybody know how to fix this?

I have tried in chrome and firefox but their output are same.

Comment: multiple pages/same page make up your mind

Comment: Are you sure the ID isn't repeated somewhere else on the page you don't get the right value? Run a check for `$('[id=idValue]').length`

Comment: @madalinivascu well, it's on the different page, I just mentioned that I am checking whether it is on the different page, that's all

Comment: @charlietfl I have used inspect element but it seems that the ID is only one, it's also proved by using some code like a that I have mentioned aboved in the script, I also tried to remove the word value from html and the output is blank, for the length, it returns one, means exist right?

Comment: b = $('#qty-'+a, this).val();, why you used 'this' after comma in this statement?

Comment: if you have different pages how do you store the infor across them ?@YukoPangestu

Comment: @ManojLodhi that is the context argument. Is explained in the docs. It is redundant however when using an ID selector

Comment: True @charlietfl, it has been mentioned in this forum that I can use that strategy but it returns undefined, So I change it back to where it was

Comment: Create a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for explain :) , i never used this before

Comment: @charlietfl I will try... hope i didn't take too much time

Comment: Not at all...but without being able to reproduce problem is hard to know why it happens, or what is going wrong

Comment: @charlietfl or should I post the whole code? Well, I can do that though... because my program is complicated

Comment: Scale the issue down to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Often when you do that you find out what causes it yourself. but if you don't put it in a sandbox site like jsfiddle, plunker, codepen etc

Comment: Hmmm, I think the problem is this problem occurs in different page, I think it is still not possible if I throw it on one page like JSFiddle and stuffs.